# Export output and command lines in R

Tags: r

I want to save as a .txt file output from my console window (which includes regression summaries) and the lines of code which accompany them. So for example, for an example dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = structure(1:9, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                             "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), col.1 = c(2.4, 5.6, 
                                                                                                    7.4, 3.5, 31.2, 2, 7.9, 5, 17.8), col.2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("cat", "dog"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "col.1", "col.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ))
```

... I want to run some summary stats:

```
summary(df1$col.1)
```

I have been playing with:

```
sink("myfile.txt", append=TRUE, split=TRUE)
```

... but only the...

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    2.0     3.5     5.6     9.2     7.9    31.2
```

... is exported.  How would I get the command lines as well as the outputs?

Many thanks.

Comment: `savehistory` can output the command history to a file, but it won't be aligned to the specific output

Comment: See Ian Fellows answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734896/r-capturing-elements-of-r-output-into-text-files