# empty output ks.test residuals auto.arima forecast package

Tags: r

I used auto.arima on a set of data to determine my arima. Then, I checked the residuals. It worked well. However I can not manage to extract them to use ks.test on them. The output is empty:

```
fit <- auto.arima(series)
summary(fit) #full output
checkresiduals(fit) #full output
ks.test(residuals(fit), rnorm) #empty output.
```

The variable series is one column. How can I get the output of my ks test on my residuals of the arima series?

Comment: it should probably be `ks.test(residuals(fit),rnorm(length(residuals(fit))))`

Comment: Nope. It looks it works well when the fit is from the arima function. I wonder if the problem comes from auto.arima.

Comment: writing rnorm doesnt' call the function though. I'm not sure how that will give you any numeric values unless you have it defined somewhere and didn't show it.

Comment: I used a dataframe: `datadf <- read.csv2(file="my_file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")` then `TS = ts(datadf[i], frequency=365)`. I deseasonalized `dec = decompose(TS, type="multiplicative")`. Actually, I got my series: `series = TS / dec$seasonal` . It is only one variable.

Comment: run `rnorm`. is there a numeric output? or just code?

Comment: It is a function. It gives the following output: `function (n, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
.Call(C_rnorm, n, mean, sd)
<bytecode: 0x55de49576e38>
<environment: namespace:stats>`

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought. Try the code i posed originally.

Comment: It works in the command line but I don't have the output in my text file.

Comment: what is the output of residuals(fit)?

Comment: The output in the command line is good: `Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  residuals(fit) and rnorm(length(residuals(fit)))
D = 0.27129, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided`. The issue is that it does not appear in my output of the text file.

Comment: What text file?

Comment: `outputname = paste("output", j, sep = "_")
sink(paste0(outputname,".txt"), append = FALSE, split = FALSE)` . I produced N outputs. j is between 1 and N.

Comment: look up capture()

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with sink. I followed the advice of Kristofersen and I used the [capture.output function as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735008/5014822) and it works.